# Check if value exists in drop down

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to determine if a value exists in a drop down list. For some reason when I run the code below it is always evaluating false whether or not the value I am searching for exists or not. Is there some different logic I need to use? TIA

```
Userselection = "Test"

Dim vListItem As ListItem = UsersDropDown.Items.FindByValue(Userselection)
If Not vListItem Is Nothing Then
 MsgBox("True")
Else
 MsgBox("False")
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you perhaps mixing the `Text` and `Value` fields? Because usually the value is an ID while the Text would be something like `Test`

Take the following ListItem

```
<asp:ListItem Text="Test" Value="25"></asp:ListItem>
```

The code

```
Dim vListItem As ListItem = UsersDropDown.Items.FindByValue("Test")
```

will return null, but the following does work

```
Dim vListItem As ListItem = UsersDropDown.Items.FindByValue("25")
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried using "FindByText" and same thing happns

Comment: Then you don't use the correct value or the DLL does not contain a ListItem with those values. Can you show sample data and how you are filling the DLL with data?

Comment: I am just using a SQL data source to fill the DLL and use Request.QueryString("User") from the previous page to bring over the selected item in the drop down to be selected on page load